# Durga Kavach - Please confirm the correct version

Tags: durga, kavacha

I've been asked to read Durga Kavach daily. Until now, I was reading this:
https://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/durga-saptashati/patha-vidhi/devi-kavacham/durga-saptashati-devi-kavacham.html

But today I discovered another version here:
http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Durga_Kavacham

Even on YouTube, there is confusion. Please let me know which version is correct, as it is very important that I read it correctly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should ask the person who has asked you to read the Kavacham. By Durga Kavacham is usually meant the one from Tantra (the one from Hindupedia). The one from Purana is popularly known as Devi Kavacham. Although Devi and Durga are the same only the person can confirm which one he wants you to read.

Comment: Yes, I will ask him. Thank you for your response.

Comment: He replied that I can read any one of my choice.

Comment: That's cool ...

Comment: I've decided to continue with the one I'm reading now although it is much longer and I struggle with reading Sanskrit. What are your thoughts?

Comment: It's your choice. You can shift to the one you find easier to chant. Since you already got permission from your guide. The Durga Kavacha from the Tantra is very short. It does not take much time to read it.

Comment: Does it (the one from Tantra) need initiation? I know that anyone is allowed to read Chandi / Devi Kavach.

Comment: You can read it. If you worry about initiation you might never read anything. So please go ahead.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one you are reading is devi kavacham/durga kavacham,
https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/dkavach.html which is found in markandeya purana. Shree Durga Kavacham/Devyakavacham is a part of **Durga Saptshati / Devi Mahatmya.**

The one you found is from kubjikatantra (https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/durgAkavach.html). **So what you are reading is perfectly fine.** (Also, as Rickross's comment says, you must ask the person for the appropriate)

Wait, there is more to it: The fact that surprized me too after I searched for durga kavacham. I seriously dont know anything about these.

Durga kavacham of Brhamandamohanakyam( https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/durgaakavach2.html)

Durga kavacham of MundalaTantra : (siddha sidhaswari ) https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/durgAkavacham3.html

Durga kavacham of MundalaTantra: (Parvati Mastak Patu) https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/durgAkavacham4.html

Durga Kavacham for vaMsha vRRiddhikaraM, : https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/vanshavRiddhikaradurgAkavacha.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also had no idea that there are so many versions. I will ask the person to confirm. Also, this sanskritdocuments link is very useful, thank you.

Comment: He replied that I can read either one.

Comment: Great! Glad to help you!!

Comment: I've decided to continue with the one I'm reading now although it is much longer and I struggle with reading Sanskrit. Do you agree?

Comment: As you like it, dont worry about sanskrit it eventually becomes perfect.

Comment: Thank you! I will try :-)

Comment: This is very helpful info, thx for posting this 